# Overriding CXXFLAGS for a single translation unit in a cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ file, which implements a benchmark, that begins like this:

```
#ifdef YOMM2_BENCHMARK_HIERARCHIES
enum { NH = YOMM2_BENCHMARK_HIERARCHIES };
#else
enum { NH = 10 };
#endif
#ifdef YOMM2_BENCHMARK_OBJECTS
enum { OBJECTS = YOMM2_BENCHMARK_OBJECTS };
#else
enum { OBJECTS = 1000 };
#endif
```

I want to compile (and run) that program with different values of `NH` and `NOBJECT`. Is it possible to do that without re-generating the build system (i.e. re-running `cmake`)?

I have tried things like this:

```
touch tests/benchmarks.cpp ; CXXFLAGS="-DYOMM2_BENCHMARK_HIERARCHIES=3" make -C build/code/tests benchmarks
```

...but it doesn't work (although it probably shows what I am attempting to do).

Comment: Why don't you want to re-run `cmake`?

Comment: The question title has very little to do with the question body. The builds that CMake generates are not parameterized. You will be best served by setting these as CMake variables and re-running CMake.

Comment: Why not put the appropriate defines in a header file and perhaps make sure that a standard version of the file gets used in the release version, if that's desired. If you just put this info somewhere in the cmake project even if you don't manually reconfigure the project any build should automatically result in a cmake reconfiguration being triggered...

Comment: @Alex - difficult to express what I want to do in the title, sorry.


@Stephen I want to run the benchmark many times, using bash loops, varying the number of hierarchies and objects. I would like to avoid running `cmake` all the time, but, there is no other solution, I will do it. But, as Fabian points out:


@fabian Yes I considered that. Have a default version, and have my script overwrite the file.

Comment: Also, if you wonder why passing command-line arguments to the program: it is because I am attempting to measure the performance of virtual functions vs open methods. It's tricky. The benchmark uses TMP to generate hierarchies of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set per-target compile definitions with

```
target_compile_definitions( testexe PUBLIC YOMM2_BENCHMARK_OBJECTS )
```

That will add "-DYOMM2_BENCHMARK_OBJECTS" to that target's compile command line.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html

Comment: The question asks about a translation unit, not a target.

Comment: They do not specifically say that though " I want to compile (and run) **that program** with different values"